# Need to hook into a javascript function call, any way to do this?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hook into a function that loads Facebook's news feed:

```
UIIntentionalStream.instance && UIIntentionalStream.instance.loadOlderPosts();
```

on Facebook.com.

Is there a way for me to do this with my own JavaScript? Basically, I need to have some sort of callback - when that function is called, I'd like my own function to be called.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var old = UIIntentionalStream.instance.loadOlderPosts;
UIIntentionalStream.instance.loadOlderPosts = function() {
    // hook before call
    old();
    // hook after call
};
```

Just hook in wherever you want, before or after the original function's call.

Comment: maybe suggest wrapping the function instead of monkeypatching it

Answer (score 37):

A more complete method will be:

```
var old = UIIntentionalStream.instance.loadOlderPosts;
UIIntentionalStream.instance.loadOlderPosts = function(arguments) {
    // hook before call
    var ret = old.apply(this, arguments);
    // hook after call
    return ret;
};
```

This makes sure that if `loadOlderPosts` is expecting any parameters or using this, it will get the correct version of them as well as if the caller expects any return value it will get it

Comment: The `arguments` parameter to your function isn't actually doing anything here. `arguments` is a keyword in Javascript. It's available inside the function regardless of the parameters, so your function should simply be `function()`.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on the previous posts: I have created a function that you can call to perform this "hooking" action.

```
hookFunction(UIIntentionalStream.instance, 'loadOlderPosts', function(){
    /* This anonymous function gets called after UIIntentionalStream.instance.loadOlderPosts() has finished */
    doMyCustomStuff();
});



// Define this function so you can reuse it later and keep your overrides "cleaner"
function hookFunction(object, functionName, callback) {
    (function(originalFunction) {
        object[functionName] = function () {
            var returnValue = originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);

            callback.apply(this, [returnValue, originalFunction, arguments]);

            return returnValue;
        };
    }(object[functionName]));
}
```

Bonus: You should also wrap this all a closure, for good measure.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Eric's answer above.  When using ES6, this function works for both async and sync functions:

```js
export function createHook(obj, targetFunction, hookFunction) {
    let temp = obj[targetFunction]
    obj[targetFunction] = function (...args) {
        let ret = temp.apply(this, args)
        if (ret && typeof ret.then === 'function') {
            return ret.then((value)=>{hookFunction([value, args]); return value;})
        } else {
            hookFunction([ret, args])
            return ret
        }
    }
}
```