# How to inject javascript code to the beginning of every prototype method?

Tags: javascript

I want to inject code in javascript, for debugging purposes, within **every one** of my method prototypes in javascript. This example shows one class only, but **assume I have hundreds of classes and each class has dozens of methods**. This mechanism should perform at prototype level without the need to specify each class/method name.

```
function MyClass1() {
    this.attrib = "ABC";
}

MyClass1.prototype.myMethod = function() {
   alert("first row");  // <---- THE INJECTION SHOULD OCCUR BEFORE THIS LINE OF CODE
}
```

The idea is to **dynamically** inject some code before the first row of myMethod(), during the first loading/execution of the javascript code. Such as:

```
MyClass1.prototype.myMethod = function() {
   alert("I was injected dynamically");
   alert("first row");
}
```

So for every other Class and Method, the same should happen. Is this achievable using the Function.prototype approach ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to hook into a javascript function call, any way to do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273309/need-to-hook-into-a-javascript-function-call-any-way-to-do-this)

Comment: I hope you're not planning to display debug info using `alert`. Use `console.log` or `console.debug` instead (if supported).

Comment: Even ``console.log`` can't be relied on. It'll crash Internet Explorer unless the developer tools have been opened.

Comment: I used "alert" simply for the purpose of this inquiry. The debug that I plan to perform is based on a specific controlling global object.

Comment: regarding the duplication, I am trying to perform this dynamically for all classes and all methods. I am ensuring my question specifies this more clearly. thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just wrap your method. Here is the standard method:

```
MyClass1.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    alert("first row");
}
```

Then wrap it:

```
var orig = MyClass1.prototype.myMethod;
MyClass1.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    alert('Injected');
    return orig.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

You are asking two questions, and I've only answered one of them (i.e. how to wrap a function). The other part - how to do this on many functions - is best done using a specialized library. In fact, this can be done using [Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). I found a couple of JavaScript libraries that offers this, one of them is [Aop.js](http://mulli.nu/2010/05/07/aop-js.html) (try googling for more yourself).

Comment: Instead of `orig = MyClass1.prototype;` maybe you meant `var orig = MyClass1.prototype.myMethod;` ?