# How to know if a function is async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-next

I have to pass a function to another function, and execute it as a callback. The problem is that sometimes this function is async, like:

```
async function() {
 // Some async actions
}
```

So I want to execute `await callback()` or `callback()` depending on the type of function that it is receiving.

Is there a way to know the type of the function??

Comment: Don't try to detect it and do different things depending on what you get. Clearly document whether you support callbacks that return promises or not, then treat them as such. (Hint: if you `await` a non-promise, it automatically wraps it anyway)

Comment: the whole point of async is to not have callbacks, right?

Comment: @FelipeValdes - I think it's more like: the point of async is not to have to _manage_ callbacks. I have some sympathy with OP: if the function to be called is not async, then a direct call to the function will yield the value, whereas putting `await` on the call will unnecessarily introduce a promise wrapper around it and is, I guess, somewhat less efficient.

Answer (score 124):

## Theory

Native `async` functions may be identifiable [when being converted to strings](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-function-prototype-properties-toStringTag):

```
asyncFn[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction'
```

Or by [`AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) constructor:

```
const AsyncFunction = (async () => {}).constructor;

asyncFn instanceof AsyncFunction === true
```

This won't work with Babel/TypeScript output, because `asyncFn` is regular function in transpiled code, it is an instance of `Function` or `GeneratorFunction`, not `AsyncFunction`. To make sure that it won't give *false positives* for generator and regular functions in transpiled code:

```
const AsyncFunction = (async () => {}).constructor;
const GeneratorFunction = (function* () {}).constructor;

(asyncFn instanceof AsyncFunction && AsyncFunction !== Function && AsyncFunction !== GeneratorFunction) === true
```

Since native `async` functions were officially introduced to Node.js in 2017, the question likely refers to Babel implementation of `async` function, which relies on [`transform-async-to-generator`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/) to transpile `async` to generator functions, may also use [`transform-regenerator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/) to transpile generator to regular functions.

The result of `async` function call is a promise. [According to the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait#awaiting-non-promise), a promise or a non-promise may be passed to `await`, so `await callback()` is universal.

There are only few edge cases when this may be needed. For instance, native `async` functions use native promises internally and don't pick up global `Promise` if its implementation was changed:

```
let NativePromise = Promise;
Promise = CustomPromiseImplementation;

Promise.resolve() instanceof Promise === true
(async () => {})() instanceof Promise === false;
(async () => {})() instanceof NativePromise === true;
```

This may affect function behaviour (this is a known problem for [Angular and Zone.js promise implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49287143/3731501)). Even then it's preferable to detect that function return value is not expected `Promise` instance instead of detecting that a function is `async`, because the same problem is applicable to any function that uses alternative promise implementation, not just `async` ([the solution to said Angular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284122/angular-data-binding-wont-work-with-async-await-yet-it-will-with-promises/49287143#49287143) is to wrap `async` return value with `Promise.resolve`).

## Practice

From the outside, `async` function is just a function that unconditionally returns native promise, therefore it should be treated like one. Even if a function once was defined `async`, it can be transpiled at some point and become regular function.

### A function that can return a promise

In ES6, a function that potentially returns a promise can be used with `Promise.resolve` (lets synchronous errors) or wrapped `Promise` constructor (handles synchronous errors):

```
Promise.resolve(fnThatPossiblyReturnsAPromise())
.then(result => ...);

new Promise(resolve => resolve(fnThatPossiblyReturnsAPromiseOrThrows()))
.then(result => ...);
```

In ES2017, this is done with `await` (this is how the example from the question is supposed to be written):

```
let result = await fnThatPossiblyReturnsAPromiseOrThrows();
...
```

### A function that should return a promise

Checking if an object is a promise is [a matter of a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-do-i-tell-if-an-object-is-a-promise), but generally it shouldn't be too strict or loose in order to cover corner cases. `instanceof Promise` may not work if global `Promise` was replaced,  `Promise !== (async () => {})().constructor`. This can happen when Angular and non-Angular applications interface.

A function that requires to be `async`, i.e. to always return a promise should be called first, then returned value is checked to be a promise:

```
let promise = fnThatShouldReturnAPromise();
if (promise && typeof promise.then === 'function' && promise[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'Promise') {
  // is compliant native promise implementation
} else {
  throw new Error('async function expected');
}
```

**TL;DR: `async` functions shouldn't be distinguished from regular functions that return promises. There is no reliable way and no practical reason to detect non-native transpiled `async` functions.**

Comment: This is not working on my end. `AsyncFunction !== Function` is always false even though I have functions with keyword `async` passed as an argument to an `it()` spec. I am using Typescript by the way. Could you please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060405/how-to-programmatically-find-if-a-function-is-async) and provide your insights. I have been trying so many different ways but didn't succeed yet. :(

Comment: @Tums That's because `AsyncFunction !== Function` check is there to avoid *false positives*. There won't be *true positives* in transpiled code because `async` functions don't differ from regular ones in transpiled code.

Comment: I'm writing a hook function, the function takes an object, target and hook... how do i know if i have to await?

Comment: @ErikAronesty Can you provide a one-liner example? If a value can be a promise or not a promise, you need to `await`, it works for promises and non-promises. This is what the last snippet in the answer shows.

Comment: @EstusFlask:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273309/need-to-hook-into-a-javascript-function-call-any-way-to-do-this/62333813#62333813  See how I can't just 'await'... because then I'd be changing the semantics of the hooked function.

Comment: @ErikAronesty Yes, that's how it's usually done. Instead of checking if a function is `async`, you can check that its return value is native promise (`result instanceof Promise`) or thenable (``result && typeof result.then === 'function'``).

Answer (score 54):

As long as only the native async functions are used (which is usually the case), I prefer this simple way:

```
theFunc.constructor.name == 'AsyncFunction'
```

Comment: This also have the advantage to be more performant than a stringify :)

Comment: The problem with duck typing is that custom function passes this check, `theFunc = new class AsyncFunction extends Function {}`. But transpiled `async` function doesn't, `theFunc = () => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () { })`.

Comment: Of course @EstusFlask, you are totally right. If it's your case - you need a more complex solution. But in a "real world" (not super special or artificial cases) - one could use this solution, instead of overkill monster checkers. But one should be aware of what you are saying, thank you for your comment!

Comment: Why not use `=== 'AsyncFunction'` like what @theVoogie suggested?

Comment: @Alexander, in a real world non-async functions return promises all the time, just like async functions.

Comment: anyone can define `class AsyncFunction {}` and break this but i get the point that it's unlikely

Comment: @Lloyd, I’ve just tried on `node@v18.1.0` that `class AsyncFunction {}; console.log(AsyncFunction.constructor.name)` returns `Function`, because `class` is a sync function, not async one. Of cause, one cannot call `AsyncFunction()` (when it is a `class`) without `new` word, but the answer is correct to distinguish async function from sync one.

Comment: Some JS engines return theFunc.constructor.name === `Function` regardless the function type.

Answer (score 34):

Both @rnd, and @estus are correct.

But to answer the question with an actual working solution here you go

```
function isAsync (func) {
    const string = func.toString().trim();

    return !!(
        // native
        string.match(/^async /) ||
        // babel (this may change, but hey...)
        string.match(/return _ref[^\.]*\.apply/)
        // insert your other dirty transpiler check

        // there are other more complex situations that maybe require you to check the return line for a *promise*
    );
}
```

This is a very valid question, and I'm upset that someone down voted him. The main usecase for this type of checking is for a library/framework/decorators.

These are early days, and we shouldn't downvote **VALID** questions.

Comment: I guess the problem with this question is that it is XY problem. As it was already mentioned, async functions just return promises, so they shouldn't be detected at all. Btw, they cannot be reliably detected in minified transpiled code, `_ref` won't be there.

Comment: A slight issue beyond this, is a lot of times people will wrap node-style callbacks into promise wrappers to use with async functions, so the function may be async to a reasonable degree, but not really async.  await may work in either case... where it could get complicated is async generators.

Comment: This is still a valid question, though. In code that only uses async and await, it matters to know whether a function was declared async or not, and it is irrelevant how async/await was imlemented under the hood. For example, if your API wrapper needs to make sure that a handler was declared async, so that it can throw an error the user can fix, then you want an answer to the original question, and this one will do just fine. So to add to this answer: another way to check natively is `fn.constructor.name`, which will be `AsyncFunction` for async functions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The question resulted from incorrect understanding of `await` semantics. It doesn't matter if a function is `async` in any practical scenario I'm aware of. `async` is just a function that unconditionally returns native promise - and should be treated like one. `async` can become transpiled at some point, this shouldn't ruin an app. For the scenario you describe it's correct for a wrapper to call a function and assert a value to be promise, not assert a function to be `async`. If it needs to prevent invalid handlers ASAP, this has to be enforced at design time with TS/Flow

Comment: Remember that just because you aren't aware of any practical scenario, that doesn't mean [there are none](https://github.com/pomax/socketless). So that's something new to learn: you can discover whether a function is async or not, which means you can write code that will "do things" with or to async functions while leaving regular functions alone (or vice versa). Is it useful for normal code? No, I also can't think of a scenario in which you'd need that. But is that important for code analysis, AST builders, or transpilers that are themselves written in JS? Yeah: pretty important, actually.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for sharing. You use `async` check there, don't you? You have to be aware that client lib will make Angular users suffer because the framework requires `async` to be transpiled in order for change detection to work (and server lib will affect Electron+Angular apps). It's possible to use `async` for semantic purposes but I'd consider it a misuse, this is what decorators are for. Extra data in method names like you did with `:` is also common. It's surely needed for code analysis but that's a reasonable exception, not something that regular users look here for.

Comment: If Angular isn't compatible with `async`, then that's a good reason to not use Angular, frankly. Plenty of other frameworks, and modern vanilla JS, to pick from. As for what someone might use this for: I'm hardly a regular user, and yet I commented here because that's that SO post that Google found me when I was looking for a decent way to check for async-ness. Good stackoverflow answers help everyone, not just regular users ;)

Comment: Suffered this in an API where we rather loosely allow `function(resolve, reject)`, `async function()` or `Promise`.  The second two can be detected rather easily if a transpiler isn't involved.  Once the transpiler gets involved, it's pretty much impossible to detect the difference between `async` and `function(resolve, reject)`.    Unfortunately, due to minification, the proposed solution is just shy of working.  It's too bad that the transpiler didn't leverage a Promise pollyfill, which would have been easier to detect. :/

Comment: Any new update?

I got this issue after building a react app with typescript (Didn't happen in compile time or dev run time).

here is my solution:
``` lang-ts
const isAsyncCompiled =
  /((\.(then|catch)\s*\()|(^async\s+)|(\s+new\s+Promise\s*\()|(\s+Promise\.)|(\s+await\s+))/;


export const isAsync = (func: any) => {
  return isAsyncCompiled.test(func.toString());
};
```

Answer (score 18):

**In case you're using NodeJS 10.x or later**

Use the [native util function](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_types_isasyncfunction_value).

```
   util.types.isAsyncFunction(function foo() {});  // Returns false
   util.types.isAsyncFunction(async function foo() {});  // Returns true
```

Do keep all the concerns in mind from above ansers though. A function that just returns by accident a promise, will return a false negative.

And on top of that (from the docs):

> Note that this only reports back what the JavaScript engine is seeing; in particular, the return value may not match the original source code if a transpilation tool was used.

But if you use `async` in NodeJS 10 and no transiplation. This is a nice solution.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that `await` can be used for normal functions too. I'm not sure if it can be considered "good practice" but here it is:

```
async function asyncFn() {
  // await for some async stuff
  return 'hello from asyncFn' 
}

function syncFn() {
  return 'hello from syncFn'
}

async function run() {
  console.log(await asyncFn()) // 'hello from asyncFn'
  console.log(await syncFn()) // 'hello from syncFn'
}

run()
```

Comment: `await` will promisify normal fucntions

Answer (score 8):

**Here is a short and useful approach provided by David Walsh in his [blogpost](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-detect-async-function?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Bludice%20%28David%20Walsh%20Blog%29):**

```
const isAsync = myFunction.constructor.name === "AsyncFunction";
```

Cheers!

Comment: –1. This approach was already described in an earlier answer.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

Short answer: Use `instaceof` after [exposing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unexposed) `AsyncFunction` - see below.

Long answer: Don't do that - see below.

### How to do it

You can detect whether a function was declared with the `async` keyword

When you create a function, it shows that it's a type Function:

```
> f1 = function () {};
[Function: f1]
```

You can test it with the `instanceof` operator:

```
> f1 instanceof Function
true
```

When you create an async function, it shows that it's a type AsyncFunction:

```
> f2 = async function () {}
[AsyncFunction: f2]
```

so one might expect that it can be tested with `instanceof` as well:

```
> f2 instanceof AsyncFunction
ReferenceError: AsyncFunction is not defined
```

Why is that? Because the AsyncFunction is not a global object. See the docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction

even though, as you can see, it's listed under `Reference/Global_Objects`...

If you need easy access to the `AsyncFunction` then you can use my `unexposed` module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/unexposed

to get either a local variable:

```
const { AsyncFunction } = require('unexposed');
```

or to add a global `AsyncFunction` alongside other global objects:

```
require('unexposed').addGlobals();
```

and now the above works as expected:

```
> f2 = async function () {}
[AsyncFunction: f2]
> f2 instanceof AsyncFunction
true
```

### Why you shouldn't do it

The above code will test whether the function was created with the `async` keyword but keep in mind that what is really important is not how a function was created but whether or not a function returns a promise.

Everywhere where you can use this "async" function:

```
const f1 = async () => {
  // ...
};
```

you could also use this:

```
const f2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
});
```

even though it was not created with the `async` keyword and thus will not be matched with `instanceof` or with **any other method posted in other answers**.

Specifically, consider this:

```
const f1 = async (x) => {
  // ...
};

const f2 = () => f1(123);
```

The `f2` is just `f1` with hardcoded argument and it doesn't make much sense to add `async` here, even though the result will be as much "async" as `f1` in every respect.

### Summary

So it is possible to check if a function was created with the `async` keyword, but use it with caution because you when you check it then most likely you're doing something wrong.

Comment: What I can understand with "Why you shouldn't do it", it's fine to check if a function is declared with `async` to know if it is doing some async/await operation inside but returning nothing.

Comment: @AmitGupta It doesn't return nothing. It returns a promise.

Comment: If you have a codebase that mixes async/await (which requires knowing nothing about promises) and promise functions, really _that's_ the thing you shouldn't be doing. The nice thing about async/await is that the implementation details become irrelevant: you don't `then().catch()` an async function, you `try/await` it instead. So yeah, you totally _should_ check the function's type if you leitimately need to know whether it's async or not, but not by using `instanceof`: use `fn.constructor.name` instead. If it's `AsyncFunction` instead of `Function`, you know it's an async function.

Answer (score 3):

> So I want to execute await callback() or callback() depending on the
> type of function that it is receiving.

You could always execute it with `await` and it will do the right thing:

```
async function main(callback) {
  let result = await callback(); // even if callback is not async
  // use 'result'
}
```

> Is there a way to know the type of the function??

Maybe what you're actually interested in is the type of the *result* of the function. Dariusz Filipiak's answer is good but it can be even more concise:

```
async function main(callback) {
  let result = callback();
  if (result instanceof Promise) {
    result = await result;
  }
  // use 'result'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assume at begin that callback is promise:

```
export async function runSyncOrAsync(callback: Function) {

  let promisOrValue = callback()
  if (promisOrValue instanceof Promise) {
    promisOrValue = Promise.resolve(promisOrValue)
  }
  return promisOrValue;
}
```

and them in your code you can do this:

```
await runSyncOrAsync(callback)
```

which will solve your problem with unknowing callback type....

Answer (score 1):

## Full Solution: Handle both Async and Promise

I always use Promises and async/await interchangeably, as they are basically the same.

> Async/Await is used to work with promises in asynchronous functions. It is basically syntactic sugar for promises. It is just a wrapper to restyle code and make promises easier to read and use.
> Source: [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-promise-and-async-await-in-node-js/)

If you need a helper function to determine if a value is an [asynchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), without invoking it, or if a value is a function that returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you have arrived at the right post.

In this example I will present three different approaches.

1. Check if function is an async/await function.
2. Check if a regular function returns a Promise.
3. Check both.

### Handle Async Functions

This function can determine if a function was defined using the `async` keyword.

#### Example functions to validate

```
async function a() {}
const b = async () => {}
```

#### Validation function

```
function isAsyncFunction(f: unknown): boolean {
  return f && f.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction'
}
```

### Handle Promise Functions

This function can determine if a regular function returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). In order assess if the given function returns a Promise, we need to invoke the function and examine the returned value. To avoid multiple invocations of the same function, we can return the the aforementioned value if it's a Promise, and `false` if it's not.

#### Example functions to validate

```
function a() { return new Promise(() => {}) }
const b = () => new Promise(() => {})
```

#### Validation function

```
function isPromiseFunction<T>(fn: any, ...params: any[]): Promise<T> | boolean {
    const isFunction = fn && typeof fn === 'function'
    const notAsyncFunction = fn.constructor.name !== 'AsyncFunction'
    if (isFunction && notAsyncFunction) {
        const value = fn(...params) || false
        if (value && value.constructor.name === 'Promise') {
            return value as Promise<T>
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

### Handle both

Because both [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) and [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are essentially the same, we can just check if they both return a Promise.

```
function isAsync<T>(fn: any, ...params: any[]): Promise<T> | boolean {
    const isFunction = fn && typeof fn === 'function'
    if (isFunction) {
        const value = fn(...params) || false
        if (value && value.constructor.name === 'Promise') {
            return value as Promise<T>
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

### Conclusion

Asynchronous functions are faster and cleaner to validate, whereas promise functions need to be invoked in order to be validated.

### Test Functions (CodePen)

https://codepen.io/isakhauge/pen/gOGGQPY

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading of GeeksForGeeks to say that  _"Async/Await ... is basically syntactic sugar"_ . Using `await` on a call to any function fundamentally changes the execution sequence, When `await` is applied to a sync function call, the result is that the async function within which the call is made will return an unresolved promise at the point of the `await` even though the called sync function has already completed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of testing if a function that you want to call efficiently is an async function (i.e. returns a `Promise`), you can call it without `await`, check if the returned value is a promise, and only then await it:

```js
let result = someFunctionWhichMayBeAsync()
if (typeof result?.then === 'function') {
   result = await result
}
```

This approach will work with genuine async functions, and anything which returns a `Promise` (or [thenable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#thenables). The only caveat is it could fail if a value is returned which has a `.then` method which is not actually a thenable (but so would calling `await` or `Promise.resolve()` unconditionally in that circumstance, so there isn't really anything better you can do).

FWIW it may not be any more performant than just `await`ing the return value unconditionally, as checking the value of `.then` might be more expensive than the overhead of `await` - here's a [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/hklf70jyay/1).