# AsyncFunction is not defined, yet MDN documents it's usage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, standards

There is an article [AsyncFunction - JavaScript on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction). It shows the following snippet:

```
new AsyncFunction([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
```

Yet in both Mozzila Firefox 55 and Google Chrome, this constructor is not defined at all:

[image]
[image]

I found out that `(async function() {}).constructor` really is `AsyncFunction`, but why can't I see it in global scope?

Comment: Hmm... You did'n read the docs carefully enough, "_Note that AsyncFunction is not a global object ..._".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in the Mozilla docs "Note that AsyncFunction is not a global object."

Therefore you can't access it as a property of the `window` object like other global constructors. It must be obtained by interrogating an instance of an `async` function:

From the docs:

```
const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
```

Comment: Is there any reason for that?

Comment: It doesn't mention why, but I imagine it could be to encourage usage of the `async` keyword over raw instantiation, while still providing some access for programmatic usage such as your example.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation itself is confused so it's no wonder that people get confused as well.

MDN docs tell us that **AsyncFunction is not a global object**, and yet they list it in the **Global Objects** reference! Oops!

- https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction

This leads to unexpected behavior. This works:

```
> f1 = function () {};
[Function: f1]
> f1 instanceof Function
true
```

But this doesn't:

```
> f2 = async function () {}
[AsyncFunction: f2]
> f2 instanceof AsyncFunction
ReferenceError: AsyncFunction is not defined
```

I wrote an `unexposed` module that you can use:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/unexposed

It basically works like the example in the answer by Patrick but you don't have to remember it.

See also this question for more info:

- [How to know if a function is async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508420/how-to-know-if-a-function-is-async/49166833#49166833)