# How to programmatically find if a function is async?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to override (monkey patch) the `it()` function of the Jasmine framework and in the process, I want to know if a function which is passed as the second argument to the `it()` function is of type `async` or not. I tried using the `instanceof Promise` because all `async` functions return a promise, but it never resolves to true and it never goes into the if block in the following code block. I have tried logging all the functions to the console and I found that all the `async()` function specs have a return type of `tslib_1.awaiter(some args..)`.

Here is what I have:

```
let newIt = jasmine.getEnv().it;
jasmine.getEnv().it = function(...args): jasmine.Spec {
  // do something.
 if(args[1] instanceOf Promise) {
   debugger; // never comes in here.
   // catch error.
 }
 return newIt.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Could anyone please point me into a right direction?

Thank you.

Edit: Let's say I have the following two dummy specs, one is async and the other is synchronous:

Async Test:

```
const exp = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(1);
                }, 500);
            });
        };

 it('asyncTest', async () => {
      expect(await exp()).toEqual(1);
  }, 600);
```

Synchronous:

```
it('testNon', () => {
     expect(true).toBe(true);
 });
```

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want this?

Comment: In the latest Jasmine, when you write async tests, it doesn't throw console errors correctly which helps me in debugging in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is XY problem. As pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38510353/3731501) there is usually no need to check that it's `async` function because this doesn't matter. `async` function is just a function that returns a promise. Both `() => Promise.resolve()` and `async () => {}` should be treated in same way.

This is confirmed by the fact that it's impossible to distinguish between `async` and regular function in transpiled TypeScript code - both of them are just regular functions.

`args[1] instanceOf Promise` is incorrect, because a function won't be an instance of `Promise`.
Monkey-patching is generally performed this way (this isn't specific to Jasmine or this case):

```
let newIt = jasmine.getEnv().it;
jasmine.getEnv().it = function(...args): jasmine.Spec {
  const fn = args[1];
  let newFn;
  if (fn.length > 0) {
    // async spec with done param
    newFn = function (done) {
      const result = fn.call(this, done);
      if(result instanceOf Promise)
      // or even better,
      // if(result && typeof result.then === 'function')
        debugger;
      return result;
    }
  } else {
    newFn = function () {
      const result = fn.call(this);
      if(result instanceOf Promise)
        debugger;          
      return result;
    }
  }

  args[1] = newFn;
  return newIt.apply(this, args);;
}
```

It's test function *result* that should be checked to be an instance of `Promise` (or to be checked if it's thenable).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearly explaining it and pointing out the correct way of the monkey patching. It's weird that even now, the condition never becomes true and never hits the debugger.

Comment: Sorry, monkey patching went wrong there. Updated the code, guess this should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for taking too long to accept your answer. You rock. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because the async functions always return a promise, but they aren't in themselves promises.

The simple answer is to look at the constructor of the function in question (but I'll explain why you shouldn't after):

```
const isAsync = func.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction';
```

The problem with this approach is that async functions aren't really meant to be distinguishable from regular functions which return a promise. It would be better to use `Promise.resolve` to turn the result of any function call into a `Promise`, and `await` that.

Comment: could you please give me a simple example how I could implement this in my case? I have updated my code with a couple of simple `it` specs which can be used in the scenario.

Comment: Are you saying, I should do something like this: `let x = Promise.resolve(args[1]);`  And then check `if(p instanceof Promise){ // do something}` ? I didn't quite get the `await` part.