# How do I know that a particular operation is asynchronous in javascript?

Tags: javascript, npm

This is in reference to npm libraries.

How do I know that a particular operation or function from the library is asynchronous, in which I have to use the async await syntax.

Comment: If you don't know, it's safe to treat it as though it is!

Comment: Read the documentation

Comment: Does the function take a callback or return a promise. If so it is almost certainly asynchronous.

Comment: These features are sort of stitched together in JS. They decided to have the standard library include a `Promise` library, which then became the basis for `async/await`. So there's language-level functionality, but not language-level enforcement.

Comment: Would be nicer if JS decided to have `async` functions that couldn't be called without `await`, and that had a way for the `async` function to signal its completion and result without having this library in between.

Comment: I assume this is server-side code. You may be happier in a language that has first class support for concurrent/asynchronous code handling. We're stuck with JS in the browser (for now), but there are much more comfortable languages outside of that environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if a function is async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508420/how-to-know-if-a-function-is-async)

Answer (score -1):

Async/Await build on Promises, so functions that return promises can be awaited. If a function takes a callback it is typically asynchronous as well, but cannot be awaited. [You can however transform such APIs to provide Promise objects and in turn await those.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)