# Assertion error when testing async function with mocha and chaiAsPromised

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

So i am trying to test that my async function throws an error when I stub `s3GetObject = Promise.promisify(s3.getObject.bind(s3))` to be rejected with `blah` however i am getting that my function is not async and it does not throw an error.

below is my `main.js` file with the `tests.js` of this:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
});

const s3GetObject = Promise.promisify(s3.getObject.bind(s3));

async function getS3File(){
  try {
    const contentType = await s3GetObject(s3Params);
    console.log('CONTENT:', contentType);
    return contentType;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
   throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

Testing:

```
    /* eslint-env mocha */
const rewire = require('rewire');
const chai = require('chai');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai);
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe('Main', () => {

  describe('getFileFromS3', () => {
    let sut, getS3File, callS3Stub;

    beforeEach(() => {
      sut = rewire('../../main');
      getS3File = sut.__get__('getS3File');
      sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      console.log.restore();
    });

    it('should be a function', () => {
      getS3File.should.be.a('AsyncFunction');
    });

    describe('with error', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        callS3Stub = sinon.stub().rejects('blah');
        sut.__set__('s3GetObject', callS3Stub);
        getS3File = sut.__get__('getS3File');
      });

      it('should error with blah', async () => {
        await getS3File.should.throw();
        //await console.log.should.be.calledWith('blah');

      });
    });
  });
});
```

The errors I am getting are:
  1) Main

> getFileFromS3
>            should be a function:
>        AssertionError: expected [Function: getS3File] to be an asyncfunction
>         at Context.it (test\unit\main.spec.js:28:27)

2) Main

> getFileFromS3
>        with error
>          should error with blah:  AssertionError: expected [Function: getS3File] to throw an error
>
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: blah
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with `.catch(). (rejection id: 228)`

Comment: getS3File = sut.__get__('getS3File'); . this line is causing issue i think . ur changing the async function reference to some other value . change the getS3File variable name to something else and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508420/how-to-know-if-a-function-is-async), it doesn't matter whether a function is `async` or not, as long as it returns a promise. Chai relies on [`type-detect`](https://github.com/chaijs/type-detect) to detect types and detects `async` function as `function`.

It should be:

```
getS3File.should.be.a('function');
```

`async` functions are syntactic sugar for promises, they don't throw errors but return rejected promises.

It should be:

```
getS3File().should.be.rejectedWith(Error);
```