# How to check if NodeJS program is about to exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, event-loop

Say someone implemented a different setTimeout function:

```
const setTimeout = (func, ms) => {
  const future = Date.now() + ms;
  while (Date.now() < future) {
    // do nothing
  }
  func();
};
```

Which (for the simplicity of this question) has almost the same interface as the original one.
How can I, as a developer using it, can verify it did not initialize any async code?

I want to know if my program will exist after I use the `setTimeout` call.
If the `setTimeout` is implemented using sync code, the program will exist (shortly) after.
If the implemenation of `setTimeout` is async, the program will exist only after the async code is done.

More specifically, can I do something like that?

```
setTimeout(()=>{},1000);
const isAnyAsyncCodeWillRun = ...;
if(isAnyAsyncCodeWillRun){
   console.log('Program wont exist right now, only in about 1000ms');
} else {
   console.log('Program will exist now');
}
```

Comment: Other than checking if the return value is a [thenable](https://promisesaplus.com/) object, there's not much you can do. Any function can make asynchronous calls without providing hooks for the caller to register, even if the function blocks for a long time.

Comment: What do you think your `setTimeout2` does?  Because I'm almost positive that it will lock the execution context until the `while` gets satisfied.  By that, I mean nothing else will execute.

Comment: Your "better" setTimeout function is just a busy loop that blocks any code from executing. If you want to be able to detect when asynchronous code is queued into the event loop you can utilize the [async_hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) module.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I’m aware of the nature of my setTimeout2 and the reason I’ve implemeted it like this was intented. @Jake thanks I’ll check that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if a function is async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508420/how-to-know-if-a-function-is-async)

Comment: If you're ok with using Node to verify, you can use `process._getActiveHandles()` and `process._getActiveRequests()` to inspect what is in the event loop, and if anything is added, (and nothing else was running asynchronously as the time) you can assume that *something* asynchronous is running.

Comment: @FaustoNA it is not a duplicate. What you linked here is a special case of async function, therefore we are talking about promises, which is one implementation of handling async code. Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 The problem is written in my 2nd example code which is: fill out line 2 (the ... part) so the following lines will work as expected. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. Ive edited the question to make it more specific and less abstract. Would appreciate new comments/answers

Comment: @dave it seems that not all async code update these counters (the immediate for example) any suggestions?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger since these hooks are also async, I was not able to use them to solve it (I've tried to generalize Bergi answer with your method). But anyhow - really nice feature - I was not aware of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the term "asynchronous" means that the function returns before it is finished doing its work, and when supplied a callback will call that later. So you can use

```
let done = false;
let returned = false;
unknownFunction(() => {
    done = true;
    if (returned) console.log("callback is getting called asynchronously");
});
returned = true;
if (done) console.log("callback was called synchronously");
```

Of course, you cannot synchronously determine whether the function will later do something asynchronously (unless your environment provides special hooks for this).

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, and it seems you understand my concerns. Given that the environment is nodejs, are there any hooks I can use to determine it synchronously?

Comment: Dave and Jake mentioned some in the comments, but I don't know the details