# How to Know If a Function passed as a parameter is async in Flutter and Wait for it?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

So my question would be a duplicate of [this javascript question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38508420/9142279) but mine is about Flutter: I have a method (it is the method `add` of class Bloc so I can't await it, I need to send a callback instead) that takes as parameter a `Function` to execute it when work is done.

```
void myMethod(Function onDone) async {
  onDone();//how to know if I should write this?
  await onDone();//or this?
}
```

How can I know when I want to execute this `Function` parameter if it is sync or async i.e. if I should write `await onDone()` or `onDone()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out no need to know if it is async or not in my case. The class `Future`has the constructor `Future.value` that takes the result of calling the callback and awaits for it automatically if it was async (i.e. if  `onDone()` returns a `Future`).

From its documentation:

> If value is a future, the created future waits for the value future to
> complete, and then completes with the same result

It can be used as: `await Future.value(onDone());` .

So in conclusion I will always use `await` for my callback but this will solve the problem in both cases whether `onDone` was synchronous or asynchronous callback

Answer (score 2):

You can await a non-async function. The Dart linter will issue a warning if it can work out that an awaited function isn't async, but it's only a warning. You can run the below code in DartPad: callbackOne is async, callbackTwo is not.

```
void main() async {
  String cb1 = await callbackOne();
  String cb2 = await callbackTwo(); //Warning here
  print("cb1=$cb1 cb2=$cb2");
  await functionWithCallback(callbackOne);
  await functionWithCallback(callbackTwo);
}

Future<void> functionWithCallback(Function callback) async {
  String foo = await callback();
  print("Callback returned $foo");
}

Future<String> callbackOne() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  return "One";
}

String callbackTwo() {
  return "Two";
}
```

Output:

```
cb1=One cb2=Two
Callback returned One
Callback returned Two
```

Comment: I don't know about dart pad's linter rules, but in android studio it looks like the linter is configured to give an error on it, that's why I thought I can't do that, actually the code even won't compile If I call `await` on a variable of type `Function`

Comment: FWIW - Just tested in vscode on Linux using "Dart from Flutter 2.5.1" and using dart cli -> The vscode linter doesn't actually issue a warning and the code runs without any error.