# How to test if function is called with async keyword

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vuejs3

I want to write a simple test for my vue3 app, test should assert that **specific function** (updateRoute in this case) is declared with **async** in different components

*Note: according to my current project I can't isolate this function in a single file to make it reusable*

example:

```js
const updateRoute = () => { doSomethig() }
```

should **fail**

while

```
const updateRoute = async () => { await doSomethig() }
```

should **pass**

the testing library doesn't matter, it can be Jest or anything else

Comment: It's not shown what is doSomethig and how updateRoute is used. It could be possibly solved with a linter. This can be XY problem. Even if it's known that updateRoute returns a promise, it's unknown that it returns a correct promise, i.e doSomethig is awaited. Generally it's preferable to assert that a place where updateRoute is used works correctly, i.e. side effects from doSomethig are applied at correct time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no reliable way and no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38510353) to detect `async` function. For a function that returns a promise, it's the same as:

```
const updateRoute = () => {
  return doSomethig().then(() => {}) // Returns a promise of undefined
}
```

It should be tested that `updateRoute` returns a promise, with `async` or not. In Jest it's:

```
expect(updateRoute()).toEqual(expect.any(Promise));
```

As for mandatory `await`, this can be handled with [ESLint `require-await` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await) if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `contructor.name` of the function is equal to `'AsyncFunction'`:

```js
const x = async () => {};
const y = () => {}

console.log(x.constructor.name);
console.log(x.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction');

console.log(y.constructor.name);
console.log(y.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction');
```