# How to ensure that function passed as prop to Vue component is async?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Is it possible to check if a prop Function is async or not?

For example, here is a prop in my component:

```
      callbackFunction: {
        type: Function,
        default: null,
      },
```

How can I validate this and make sure that the passed in Function is declared as async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [no reliable way and no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508420/how-to-know-if-a-function-is-async/38510353#38510353) to do this. It could be regular function that returns a promise with exactly the same result, and it would be impossible to detect if it's asynchronous without calling it.

There may be no reason to restrict a callback to be asynchronous. A safe way that works with any kind of result is:

```
if (this.callbackFunction) 
  await this.callbackFunction()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do with props ["validator"](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation)

```
     callbackFunction: {
        type: Function,
        validator(value) {
          if (value?.constructor?.name === 'AsyncFunction') {
             return true;
          } else {
            console.error('Function should be async');
            return false;
          }
        },
        default() {},
      },
```

Here's the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-3jycse?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FTeste.vue).

Note: This does not break anything, If a requirement is not met, Vue will warn you in the browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: More of a JS hack than a Vue thing. But clever nonetheless!

Comment: Haha, yes, anything possible with JS ;-)

Comment: It won't work with transpiled functions

Comment: wdym, what "transpiled functions"?

Comment: `async/await` wasn't there from the beginning. So if OP is using ES5 for example, that one would not be available.

Comment: No, I meant where it mentioned in the question 

Comment: It's not written in the question, but a possibility if OP transpiles to older browsers.

Comment: hmm... who's using OLDER Browsers with vue anyway... JK 

Comment: @Naren It's up to a developer how transpilation is configured and what are the reasons for this. Vue 2 supports older browsers. When Babel target is lower than ES2017, `async` function is outputted as regular function that returns a promise. They are totally equivalent in JS and there's no reliable way and no need to distinguish them in normal work.

Answer (score 1):

Props cannot be async, they can only be sync. So no, no such validation is possible.

---

Here is a detailed page on all the types available: https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#props

Btw, passing functions is an anti-pattern in Vue (it's not React).
That [blog post](https://michaelnthiessen.com/pass-function-as-prop/) could give you more insight as of how to achieve something clean in Vue.