# How to fire a callback when window variable changes using JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, webview

I have a window variable accessible in my webview like `window.x` Android/iOS is changing the value of `x` based on certain conditions, problem is this value changes but react is not able to rerender based on said change since its not a state.

Is there any way to fire a callback when this value changes without polling it continuously?

Comment: If you know which function is changing the variable, you can hook into it and add handler that runs after it. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273309/need-to-hook-into-a-javascript-function-call-any-way-to-do-this)

Comment: @Brother58697 the code triggering the variable change is running in Android/iOS native code, can I trigger an event in react from native code via a method channel or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way to communicate events to a webview running on Android/iOS, requires minor changes to native code.

[How to trigger webview events from native code](https://betterprogramming.pub/react-webviews-and-how-to-communicate-with-javascript-on-android-70543c35d37d)